# Does alter use locks internally?

Tags: concurrency, clojure

```
(def a (ref 0))
(def b (ref 0))

(def f1 (future 
           (dosync
              (println "f1 start")
              (alter a inc)
              (Thread/sleep 500)
              (alter b inc)
              (println "f1 end"))))

(def f2 (future 
           (dosync
              (println "f2 start")
              (alter a inc)
              (println "f2 end"))))

@f1 @f2
```

In the example above, I thought that the thread f2 should terminate before f1, although f1 reached the expression (alter a inc) before f2 did, but f1 continues its time-consuming execution, so f2 committed first, thus, upon commission of f1, it founds that ref a has been modified, then f1 should retry.
But the result showed I was wrong, it printed out the following:

```
f1 start
f2 start
f2 start
f2 start
f2 start
f2 start
f1 end
f2 start
f2 end
```

It's f2 that retried, it seems like f1 "locked" the ref on (alter a inc), and f2 waited for f1 to "release the lock" before f2 could successfully commit the alteration.
What is the underlying mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program illustrates one problem of the STM: when you have multiple transactions working on the same state, those transactions must essentially be serialisable, that is run serially (one after the other in its entirety).

That is why long-running transactions are really a very bad thing as they may cause all other transactions that are working on the same refs to retry, even if in theory they could finish very quickly.

[`commute`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/commute) is the tool that is provided to mitigate this problem. If *you* know that certain operations in different transactions alter the same refs but don’t (logically) interfere with each other because they are commutative operations, you can use `commute` instead of `alter` to loosen the serialisability requirement.

And yes, STM transactions use locks internally. Basically, you can think of `(alter a inc)` as obtaining the ‘write lock’ on ref `a` and failing and retrying if it is already taken – consider this an implementation detail. (There are complications: under stress, older transactions are allowed to break through a lock held by a younger transaction; also, the STM uses timeouts internally, so using timeouts in your program brings these implementation details to the surface.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to vary depending on the timing.  I tried your version and got the same results. Then I changed it a bit and got different results:

```
 (let [a  (ref 0)
        b  (ref 0)
        f1 (future
             (dosync
               (println "f1 start")
               (alter a inc)
               (Thread/sleep 500)
               (alter b inc)
               (println "f1 end")))
        f2 (future
             (dosync
               (println "f2 start")
               (alter a inc)
               (println "f2 end")))]
    (println @f1)
    (println @f2)
    (println @a)
    (println @b))
```

with results:

```
Testing tst.demo.core

f1 start
f2 start
f2 start
f2 end
f1 start
f1 end
(clojure.core/deref f1) => nil
(clojure.core/deref f2) => nil
(clojure.core/deref a) => 2
(clojure.core/deref b) => 1
```

So the detailed timing of the threads on any particular machine at any particular time seems to make a big difference.

I will admit that I am surprised, as I would have predicted the same thing as you. Neither your result nor this new one is what I would have expected.

---

**Update**

I modified it a bit and then got the expected result:

```
  (let [a  (ref 0)
        b  (ref 0)
        f1 (future
             (dosync
               (println "f1 start")
               (alter a inc)
               (Thread/sleep 500)
               (alter b inc)
               (println "f1 end")))
        f2 (future
             (dosync
               (Thread/sleep 100)
               (println "f2 start")
               (alter a inc)
               (println "f2 end")))]
    (println @f1)
    (println @f2)
    (println @a)
    (println @b))

f1 start
f2 start
f2 end
f1 start
f1 end
(clojure.core/deref f1) => nil
(clojure.core/deref f2) => nil
(clojure.core/deref a) => 2
(clojure.core/deref b) => 1
```

Comment: I am new to Clojure, what is t/spyx in your code? I got an error compiling your code

Comment: I run your code and got different results than yours, my results showed that f2 retried